# Finding Multiple Matches Using Pandas Rolling Min

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am able to get the rolling minima of a column using:

```
df['MemberLows'] = df['Members'].rolling(5, closed="left").min()
```

Is there a way of returning values that are within a tolerance of the minima without resorting to a non-vectorized approach like a for loop?

For example, given the table:

| Month | Members |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 10 |
| Feb | 10 |
| Mar | 10 |
| Apr | 6 |
| May | 5 |
| Jun | 10 |
| Jul | 10 |
| Aug | 10 |
| Sep | 10 |
| Oct | 7 |
| Nov | 8 |
| Dec | 10 |

The rolling minima would be 5 and 7. Say I would like to also return values within 20% of the minima; this would also return 6 and 8.

Ultimately I want to return two arrays. One containing the indices of the minima/those within 20% and one containing the actual values:

```
indices_arr = [3 4 9 10]

values_arr = [6 5 7 8]
```

Comment: what you want is unclear, can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: Hi @mozway I've added the expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just calculate the relevant threshold for each value and compare. Like so:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("table.tsv", delimiter="\t")
>>> result = df[df["Members"] <= (df['Members'].rolling(5, center=True, closed="left").min() * 1.2)]
>>> print(result)
   Month   Members
3    Apr         6
4    May         5
9    Oct         7
10   Nov         8
```

Two things worth noting:

- I'm assuming that values are positive (otherwise I can't just multiply by 1.2)
- I added center=True to get min value indices to correspond to indices of members.

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused by what you want. Not sure why you added `closed="left"`, you might want to consider tweaking `min_periods` instead.